# .app crashes upon launch in IOS simulator on M1

Tags: ios, xcode, automation, ios-simulator

I'm trying to launch an .app build on iOS simulator for automation purposes. My steps:

- Download an .ipa file from app distribution resource
- Unzip .ipa and get .app bundle from Payload folder
- Simply drag and drop the .app bundle on the running simulator

And.. when I try to launch the .app this simply crashes. I'm not seeing any logs though. Funny thing is that my teammate is doing this successfully and the only difference between our machines is that my one is on M1 chip and hers is on Intel.

I've also tried to check the box "Open with Rosetta" with no success.

versions:
macOS Monterey 12.0.1,
xcode and simulator 13.1

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?